# How do I recreate a message timeout function with python

Tags: python, discord

Still very new to python. I am making a discord bot that may sometimes require a timed response. In an effort to reuse code, I'm trying to set up a "timeout" function that I can call for every unique response. The timeout function, in theory, waits for a response unless timed out, then returns the response. This function causes an error at

```
response = msg_timeout()
```

"TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "coroutine") to str", but the timeout function *does* return a string. What am I doing wrong here? Below should be all of the relevant snippets of code.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  
  msg = message.content.lower()
  a_id = message.author.id
  a_name = message.author.name

  async def msg_timeout():
    def check():
      return message.author.id == a_id
    try: 
      answer = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=15.0, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
      await channel.send(a_name + "You waited too long to answer.")
      return None
    else:
      return answer

  if msg.startswith('bot play game'):
    await message.channel.send("Sure, pick one: A or B")
    response = msg_timeout()
```

Comment: Please verify the indentation of your code. If you have multiple snippets from different parts of the code, please make sure they appear in separate code blocks, and label them each with explanatory text to put them in context. Please also make sure that the code you show has a complete context; for example, where you have `a_name + "You waited too long to answer."`, where is `a_name` defined? You might also want to read http://sscce.org.

Comment: I added in the variable where it appears in the greater code. I believe it is formatted correctly now. Thank you.